# Is it advisable to mount an outdoor air-conditioner on a wall with brackets?

Tags: air-conditioning, mounting, brackets

I heard somewhere that mounting an outdoor air-conditioner unit in townhouses is not recommended, since vibration may propagate through the wall on adjacent units and thus disturb other tenants and even impact the integrity of shared walls.

Is this true? Are there exceptions to this?

To be more specific, I mean this type of AC units:

[image]

Comment: The structural integrity claim seems implausible because if true they'd also be a hazard in single family structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An air conditioner can be installed on pretty much any brick, concrete or block wall. As long as it is installed properly, there is no issues to it falling or structural integrity of the building. Air conditioners are mounted on brackets all over the world, especially where space is a premium. You can always place rubber pads between the brackets and the unit to help dampen any vibration. I suggest gently having the technician place 1 screw on either side of the brackets and condenser to keep it from being knocked off easily.

A properly leveled and mounted condenser will transfer the same amount of vibration into the building as one on a patio stone, as long as there are no issues with the unit. I find Majority of condenser/compressor vibration and noise is transferred into the home from the line set and not the brackets.